# How do I disable brace completion in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, matching, curly-braces

I have recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2012. Whenever I stand on a curly opening bracket and press tab, it automatically inserts 2 new lines and a closing bracket.

```
{|<- cursor
```

Pressing tab gives me.

```
{
    |
}
```

I wish to disable this behavior. I've searched through the settings, Google and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sffa753.aspx) for the past hour, but I've been unable to find anything that would solve my issue.

I have disabled all installed plugins to see if it would go away, but it didn't.

Comment: Your not using http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e33cb22-d4ac-4f5a-902f-aff5177cc94d ?  If you are, disable it, if not, I am not sure

Comment: This also happens when selecting a whole block from the bottom up to indent it. The cursor ends up after the `{` and pressing tab messes everything up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is being caused by a [code snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx).  Snippets can be activated by typing the snippet shortcut followed by a tab.  Visual Studio 2012 comes with several code snippets pre-installed for several different languages.  For the C++ language there a default snippet with a shortcut of `{` which expands to:

```
{

}
```

The default snippets can't be disabled easily through the default GUI, however you should be able to remove the snippet file which is located at (for English language):

```
%VSInstallDir%\VC\Snippets\1033\Visual C++\{.snippet
```

I believe there are other extensions out there for managing snippets as well.